# Beacon Ranging in the Background on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently trying to find a way to range beacons in the background in iOS by using location monitoring and then triggering the ranging like so:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, forRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if (state == .Inside) {
        locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion((region as? CLBeaconRegion)!)
    }
}
```

I'm then trying to get an API call to be made in the beacon ranging

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        for beacon in beacons {
            let minor = beacon.minor as Int
            let major = beacon.major as Int
            do {
                try APICall.canSeeBeacons(major, minor: minor)
            } catch {
                print("Error making API call")
            }
        }
    }
```

However this only works for about ten minutes while the phone is in the background, after ten minutes it no longer works but I'm hoping to make it continuous so that API calls can always be made when a beacon is found. I do also have the correct keys set in the permissions and I'm using requestAlwaysAuthorization() on my locationManager

Comment: Are you trying to range a single beacon for more than ten minutes or are having a problem where you don't get region entry/exit events after 10 minutes?

Comment: @Paulw11 It's just region entry, I need the app to make the call when it has detected a nearby beacon

Comment: What class is holding your location manager? The app delegate or a view controller?

Comment: @Paulw11 The view controller is holding the location manager

Comment: You should try holding it as a property of your app delegate and process region events there. Use NSNotifications to notify the viewcontroller

Comment: @Paulw11 So do you mean having the location manager delegate methods didRangeBeacons and didDetermineState inside the App delegate?

Comment: Yes. I have an app that uses CoreLocation geofences and beacon regions and it will get region entry events days after I have explicitly run it. I suspect that your view controller is being released in the background and along with it your `CLLocationManager` instance

Comment: @Paulw11 I've moved all location manager delegate methods into the App delegate and there isn't any detection at all now

Comment: The it is likely that you aren't initialising the location manager correctly

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the Apple's iOS Dev Library regarding Background Executions:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

If the type of your app is one of the accepted types for longer background executions, add the key `Required background modes` to your `Info.plist` with an array, containing one or more of the enabled types: `audio`, `location`, `voip`, `newsstand-content`, `external-accessory` and/or `bluetooth-central`.

Just note that this will be reviewed by Apple before publishing your app on the App Store.

**EDITED:**

I didn't use this for a while, but tested now and it seems it's even easier since Xcode 6.
Follow the steps:

**1.** Add the key `Required background modes` to your `Info.plist`

**2.** Go to `Capabilities`
[image]

**3.** Select the background mode(s) that fit.
[image]

Comment: I've got it all set in the info.plist under required background modes but it still has the issue of not doing anything after ten minutes

Comment: Have you seen I edited the answer? Also, after 10 minutes it will continue in background until the task is running, then it can be suspended. For example, if it, at some point, no longer monitors the current location or no longer plays musics etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As said a commentator I've moved location manager delegate methods into the App Delegate. And also I added this:

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```

And it works.